# Is it safe to raise the same event from multiple threads at once?

Tags: c#, events, thread-safety

I've got an event that's invoked from multiple threads. The event handlers themselves expect this (they are thread-safe). But is the actual parallel invocation safe?

```
class Raiser
{
    public static event Action E = delegate { };

    public static void RaiseE()
    {
        // Called from many threads at once
        E();
    }
}
```

I imagine this is OK because the backing delegate list is immutable and the event object reference is atomically updated, but when it comes to multithreading I'd rather be sure than guess :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; that is perfectly thread-safe.

However, if any of the handlers (or the methods they call) are not thread-safe, you will still have problems.
If this is a public API, you should clearly document which thread(s) the event may be raised on.